# Metering an audio file in an iOS application offline

Tags: ios, audio

Is there a way, sampling audio volume level data, without playing the file in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and inspect the sample data directly frame by frame. You might need a third party library to extract the raw sample data from the file.